# Is there a way to paste csv data into R instead of reading from file?

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, shiny

I am currently trying to publish a shinyapp to shinyapp.io but I am having trouble configuring my rdrop2 token to upload my data file with it. It is in csv form and I using app.R. Since I cannot upload the token on here in fear of having my Dropbox completely available online I will do my best.

The function I am using with rdrop2 is the following:

```
token <- drop_auth()
saveRDS(token, "droptoken.rds")
token <- readRDS("droptoken.rds")
drop_acc(dtoken = token)

statadata <- drop_read_csv("/shinyapp/alldata.csv")
g <- na.omit(statadata)
data <- reactive({
  g[1:input$scatterD3_nb,]
})

ui <-  fluidPage(...
```

When I run the shiny app on RStudio it is fully functional but when I deploy the app it gives me one of two errors.

```
ERROR: oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment.
```

or

```
Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.
```

neither error occurs when I am just printing it into the RStudio viewer.

While I fix this issue is there a way to simply create the data set by copying the csv file text editor version directly into r with something like

```
read.csv("country,nutsid,year,cyril_index_left,delta_cyril_left,manifesto,cyril_index_abs
,cyril_index,cyril_index_right,delta_cyril_right,Employment_15_64_,Employment_total,youth_employment,L_Employment_total,
L_youth_employment,growth, Austria,AT11,2002,-1017.925,-216.9429,-17.64,72.93657,1017.925,
0,-977.0339,1.1,0.9,0.5,-2.1,-8.9,4.7,Austria,AT11,2006,-923.9658,93.95892,
-4.308,104.4628,923.9658,0,0,0.8,0.4,-1.9,2.5,2.8,1.6", sep = ",")
```

I really do not see any other solution because shiny won't read my data from local files anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `text=` argument to `read.table` (and therefore `read.csv`):

```
x <- read.csv(text="country,nutsid,year,cyril_index_left,delta_cyril_left,manifesto,cyril_index_abs,cyril_index,cyril_index_right,delta_cyril_right,Employment_15_64_,Employment_total,youth_employment,L_Employment_total,L_youth_employment,growth
Austria,AT11,2002,-1017.925,-216.9429,-17.64,72.93657,1017.925,0,-977.0339,1.1,0.9,0.5,-2.1,-8.9,4.7
Austria,AT11,2006,-923.9658,93.95892,-4.308,104.4628,923.9658,0,0,0.8,0.4,-1.9,2.5,2.8,1.6")
```

Answer (score 7):

Sure.  Use something like this.

```
Lines <- "
header1, header2
val1, 12
val2, 23
"
con <- textConnection(lines)
data <- read.csv(con)
close(con)
```

You can simplify and have the multiline expression around `read.csv(textConnection("...here..."))` as well.

You can also paste from the clipboard, but that tends to get OS specific and less portable.